# how to change the address used by my project in VS to connect to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have several projects in VS and they all are under source control in microsoft team foundation.
Now the IP address of our TFS has changed.
In VS I have managed to add a new connection to the new IP address, and I am able to connect with it.

But my projects keep trying to connect to the old server address, how can I tell VS to use the new address for existing projects ?

Or is there a way to modify the TFS connection ?

for example
the projects are all connecting to TFS at 192.0.137.100
They should now connect to TFS at 192.168.137.100

How can I do that ?

**EDIT**
I found that in the `.sln` files there is always an entry like this

```
SccTeamFoundationServer = http://192.0.137.100:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```

would it be safe to just alter these files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to edit the `.sln`files.

So first step is to add the new IP address in VS and connect to it
Then alter the `.sln` file and correct the ip address

```
SccTeamFoundationServer = http://192.0.137.100:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```

becomes

```
SccTeamFoundationServer = http://192.168.137.100:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
```

Now open VS and open your project
I was now able to use TFS again

Repeat this for every project